# How to use Key Event in Timer?

Tags: c#, timer

I have the following code, which on key press, starts moving the two labels from top of the form to the bottom, and after reaching the bottom of the form, it stops. I have done it using the timer. Here is the code

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Key Pressed: " + e.KeyChar;
   //animate(sender, e);
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int X = random.Next(0, 1230);
    int y = X;
    label2.Location = new Point(X, 5);
    label3.Location = new Point(X + 20, 5 + 20);
    for (int i = 5; i <= 470; i++)
    {
        label2.Location = new Point(y, i);
        label3.Location = new Point(y + 20, i + 20);
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

Now during the animation (from the top of the form to the bottom), when I press the key, the animation restarts after reaching the bottom i.e. it completes the tick event and then and only then starts over or stop.

Now what I want is that whenever, during this movement of the labels from the top to bottom i.e. during the tick, if I press any key (or any specific key), the timer should stop.

In short, during the Timer1_Tick method, I want it to stop immediately on a key press.

I tried but couldn't get it to work. I hope that you folks here would help me sort this issue out and hope that you reply on your earliest. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are not really using the `Timer` in the way that it's intended to be used.  Ideally you would have an event that makes a change every time the tick event fires for a `Timer`.

Here you listen to the event and do several rounds of processing without ever returning from the handler at which point you stop the timer. This means the code will only ever process the tick event once instead of N times.

To fix this try breaking up the handler to do incremental work once per tick and only stop once the drawing is complete.  This will also allow you to handle key events in between the tick events and stop the timer.  The best place to break up the work is at the `Thread.Sleep` call (which itself should not appear in the handler)

Comment: Thank you JaredPar. The problem is that now the labels fall with very great speed and it is nearly impossible to see the text they represent. I used Thread.Sleep(1) for each iteration to control the sleep. Is there any other way I can slow this speed down?

Comment: @user3206911 try increasing the duration on the `Timer`.  Make the time between ticks at least a second.  If you only move the labels on the ticket then the time between moves will also be at least a second

Answer (score 0):

Try it is so simple

```
Public Boolean tick = false;
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
tick = !tick;
    label1.Text = "Key Pressed: " + e.KeyChar;
   //animate(sender, e);
if(tick)
    timer1.Start();
else
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

Comment: @user3206911 Did you checked this

Answer (score 0):

First of all i recommend you to use keyDown and keyUp events instead of key press. To solve your problem: simple set a bool = true on keyDown and and the bool = false on keyUp. Now you can check the bool within you tick method and do whatever you want if you detect key is being pressed.

Comment: I did it as you suggested and it seemed like the Up and Down events should do the job. Now I have removed the Thread.Sleep(1); statement and replaced it with the bool value check and it works. But the problem is that now the labels fall with very great speed and it is nearly impossible to see the text they represent. I used Thread.Sleep(1) for each iteration to control the sleep. Is there any other way I can slow this speed down?

Comment: @user3206911 Use Timer properly as sugested in other answers. Timer is for regular actions every x ms. In your case each tick - if(bool) translate by dX (or dY) else -do nothing-. And set tick frequency of your timer for speed you wish to move(or the dX/dY). (if I understood it correctly)